# Ruby on Rails - Refactoring ActiveRecord queries from the view to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, rails-activerecord

I am aware of the advice "fat models / skinny controllers" and "never put logic in the view"; however, it would help me to learn from an example. In the following, what is the best way to rewrite the code so that the query is not in the view?

**Model**

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order
 end

 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
 end
```

**Controller**

```
 @orders = Order.all
```

**View**

```
 <% @orders.each do |o| %>
 <%= Product.where("order_id = ?", o.id).count %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: There's no need to for the snippet you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want to display, but the straightforward option is to take advantage of the associations you've specified:

```
<% @orders.each do |o| %>
  <%= o.products.count %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller, you can use [eager loading](http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading?view=asciicast) to optimize your SQL calls.

```
@orders = Order.all(:include => :products)
```

Comment: It's arguable whether or not that belongs in the controller, though--IMO it depends on a few factors. It might belong in the mapping itself, it might belong in a model class method, etc.

Comment: It definitely depends, agreed.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for both of your answers. I was under the impression it would be more cut and dry. Thanks for your help!